# Gradle build not invoking JUnit

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

My gradle script for building an EAR is not running any JUnit tests I have. The command I used for invoking the script is

```
gradle build
```

I also tried

```
gradle test
```

and that also did not work.

My build structure is as follows

```
settings.gradle
gradle.properties
EARProject
    build.gradle
    META-INF
        application.xml
    lib
JARProject
    build.gradle
    src/main/java
        ....
    src/test/java
        ....
WebProject
    build.gradle
    src/test/java
    src/main/java
    WebContent
        .....
```

I am invoking the gradle command from EARPRoject directory.

What changes I need to do in order to run the test cases. Please note that if I run the gradle build command from individual projects it is working as expected.

Regards
-Albin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `EARProject` doesn't have any tests. Depending on what you want, run `gradle build` from the top directory, or from a subproject/subdirectory containing tests. Alternatively, you can run `gradle buildNeeded` from `EARProject`, which will perform a full build of all projects that `EARProject` depends upon (which presumably includes `JARProject` and `WebProject`).